# Bump and Displacement Fails to Render in the FINAL Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]I've got a interesting problem where my render is set to displace and bump in the material settings, and when set to the cycles engine, renders just fine with all my textures including bump and displacement. I've tried googling the absolute hell out of this but people have problems in other similar, but not exact areas. Here are some photos of my shader (Which I doubt, as it works in the viewport, just not final render). And an image to show you guys the before and after render. The shader is just a sample cause it's huge, but its all the same, just with different textures blended in. Here is an example of 1 plus the mix shaders and their masks.
[image: notice the lact of bump on the final render (left) vs the viewport (right)]

Comment: … You just described not having a problem: “renders just fine.” Where is the issue?

Comment: The viewport renders it fine as shown on the right. But when you press F12, and go through the final render, it does not.

Comment: Oh, I see. Hmm… modifiers?

Comment: No modifiers whatso ever, except for a subdivision subsurface modifier.... Which is actually a good point and might need to be applied brb.

Comment: Check that the subdivision surface modifier has the same number of view port subdivisions and render subdivisions. I suspect the viewport subdivisions are turned up but the render subdivisions are turned down.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't begin to express my thanks. That was exactly the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I realized you have to change the material settings on all materials you want to display the displacement. Materials Tab> Settings> Surface> Displacement> "Display Bump and Displacement" or "Diplays Displacement only"

Answer (score -1):

Remember folks, look over an unapplied modifiers and you might find your problem. In my case the subdivision modifier wasn't applied, and there for creating a lack of geometry for any bump to take place.

Comment: Was it that that modifier wasn't _applied_, or did it just have a fewer number of subdivisions set for the render than it did for the viewport?